# Can I define a function to replace torch.einsum' "sum" with any custom function？

Tags: algorithm, matrix, optimization, pytorch, tensor

I faced this problem.

I want to get a tensor C like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cbz3.png)
where
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I6Cq.png)
I know torch.einsum can do this by

```
    torch.einsum('aijk,aijh->ajkh', f, g)
```

But i don't want to use dot product, i want to replace it with a custom function. there is a naive solution.

```
        N, C , H ,W = left.shape

        cost = torch.autograd.Variable( torch.FloatTensor(N,H,W,W) ).cuda()

        for i in range(H):
            for j in range(W):
                for k in range(W):
                    cost[:,i,j,k] = self.qatm_cost(feature1=left[:,:,i,j], feature2= right[:,:,i,k])
                    #print(left[:,:,i,j].shape)
                    #print(right[:,:,i,k].shape)
```

It's to show to use, how can make it faster in some way?

Comment: You could try flattening everyother axis into the batch, keeping the required axis at the end: [a,i,j,k] -> [a, j, k, i], then flattening: [a, j, k, i] -> [a x j x k, i], and then applying your function with all other axes as a batch.

Comment: I think to do this I still need to use a loop ,it still will be slowly.thanks your ideal.